# Flutter App continues to work even when inexistent proxy is set

Tags: flutter, http-proxy

1. I have set the proxy for my wifi pointing an address that does exist
2. I have entered airplane mode with wifi on
3. The app continues to work
4. Everything else breaks

How is this possible?